# Docker COPY failed no such file or directory

Tags: docker, copy

I have a problem with my Dockerfile. I'm using the command like this: `COPY main.py /volume1/Files/ITenso-monitor`

When I build the `Dockerfile`, I get this error: `COPY failed: stat /volume1/@docker/tmp/docker-builder543642662/main.py: no such file or directory`

When I run this command:

```
RUN cd /volume1/Bestanden/ITenso-monitor/ && pwd \
 && ls
```

I get this ouput:

```
__pycache__
main.py
src
```

The whole `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM debian
FROM python:3.7
RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y git \
 && apt-get install -y openssh-server \
 && apt-get install -y python3 \
 && apt-get install -y python3-pip \
 && pip3 install requests
RUN git config --global user.name "username" && \
    git config --global user.password "password" && \
    git clone https://Username:Token@gitlab.com/group/repo.git /volume1/Bestanden/ITenso-monitor/
RUN cd /volume1/Bestanden/ITenso-monitor/ && pwd \
 && ls
COPY main.py /volume1/Bestanden/ITenso-monitor/
CMD ["python3", "main.py"]
```

What is causing this problem... because main.py exists in the directory.

I hope someone is able to help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you include your entire `Dockerfile` in the question?  Is the `main.py` file in the same directory on the host as the `Dockerfile`?

Comment: @DavidMaze You mean if the directory is inside the directory where the Dockerfile is located?

Comment: @DavidMaze I edited with my Dockerfile and my Dockerfile is located in ITenso-monitor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dockerfile context is your problem. Every command you give the dockerfile is executed in its context which means the current path. So if you make a copy of a file then the Dockerfile expects the file to be in the current path or a subdirectory if specified.

Let's take as an example your COPY line.

```
COPY main.py /volume1/Bestanden/ITenso-monitor/
```

Dockefile expects the path to be at

```
./Dockerfile
./main.py
```

Here is a link to the documentation https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/

Comment: Okay thanks! But can you show me how its supposed to be done? because I already red the docs, but couldn't find a solution...

Comment: Make sure Dockerfile and main.py are in the same path, directory, however you wanna call it. Otherwise specify the full path to main.py as a subdirectory where Dockerfile is located.

Comment: So did that, but it still doesn't work. My Dockerfile is located in ITenso-monitor and I have a subdir 'resources' with main.py. So with the COPY command i did these two things, but both didn't work. I did: COPY main.py ITenso-monitor/resources/ and just COPY main.py resources/. Am i not seeing the problem...

Comment: I see, change it to
COPY resources/main.py /volume1/Bestanden/ITenso-monitor/